# The problem with the reply button and the cancel reply button for WordPress comments on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I changed the way WordPress comments reply button and cancel reply button are displayed, It is displayed correctly on the desktop, but in the mobile mode, the way to display the reply button and cancel the reply is the same as the default mode of WordPres. As I said, there is no problem in desktop mode.

My php code :

```
function customize_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( get_post_type() === 'product' && is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply-', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/comment-reply.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customize_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

My JavaScript code :

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var replyClicked = false;
    $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var Comment_Container = $( this ).closest( '.comment_container' );
        if ( ! replyClicked ) {
            Comment_Container.find( '.comment-reply-link' ).hide();
            replyClicked = true;
        } else {
            $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).parent().find( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
            Comment_Container.find( '.comment-reply-link' ).hide();
        }
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
    } );
    $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var Comment_Container = $( this ).closest( '.comment_container' );
        Comment_Container.find( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
        Comment_Container.find( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).hide();
    } );
} );
```

Apparently, it interferes with `/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 4 hours of searching, I found the answer. When we put the amount on `'click'`, The condition is executed when the user has clicked on the reply button or the cancel reply button. Because we don't have anything called click in mobile, it's touch, that's why the condition inside javascript is not executed. In mobile, you should use `'touchstart'` instead of `'click'`. You need to use `'click touchstart'` to include both desktop and mobile :

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var replyClicked = false;
    $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click touchstart', function() {
        var Comment_Container = $( this ).closest( '.comment_container' );
        if ( ! replyClicked ) {
            Comment_Container.find( '.comment-reply-link' ).hide();
            replyClicked = true;
        } else {
            $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).parent().find( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
            Comment_Container.find( '.comment-reply-link' ).hide();
        }
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
    } );
    $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click touchstart', function() {
        var Comment_Container = $( this ).closest( '.comment_container' );
        Comment_Container.find( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
        Comment_Container.find( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).hide();
    } );
} );
```